# Connect to Yahoo Finance API with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, yahoo-api

I am trying to connect to Yahoo Finance API within my Flutter application, and I can´t connect.
I've seen guidance to connect to the API in different languages but there is no official guidance for Dart language.

I have the following method to connect to the API:

```
   Future<double> getStockPrice(String symbol) async {
    //var client = http.Client();
    var url = 'https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com';
    var apiStr = "/stock/v2/get-summary";
    var headers = {'x-rapidapi-key': "809135c7c7mshf35d1107bf50919p15c9fajsn37166d6b1bfc",
      'x-rapidapi-host': "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com"};
    var params = {'symbol': 'AMRN', 'region': 'US'};

    var response = await http.get(Uri.https(url, apiStr,params),headers: headers);
    //https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-summary?symbol=AMRN&region=US
    //var response = await http.get(Uri.https(url, apiStr, params));
    print('RESPONSE STATUS code: ${response.statusCode}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('RESPONSE STATUS code: ${response.statusCode}');
      var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      String value = json['price']['regularMarketOpen']['raw'];
      return double.parse(value);
    } else {
      return 0.0;
    }
  }
```

And I get null from this method. I guess it can be a matter of getting value variable, maybe I am not traversing the JSON tree correctly. But I don't see why.

Then I retrieve the data from the API in the following screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stock_analyzer/api_method/webService.dart';
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<String> test = YahooFinanceService().getWebSite('symbol');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: test,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
                return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this screen I get null. So, snapshot.data = null

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error shows that you are not authorized to make a post request, I think the error is that you are doing post instead of get.

Try changing:

```
var response = await client.post(url, body: headers);
```

To:

```
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
```

Comment: I updated the post with the situation I have now. Now I am getting null value. Thanks

Comment: Right after the get method it prints that response.body returns.  `print(response.body)` and there it should show you what you are looking for.